# How can I determine the meaning of ambiguous terminator when I tokenize my code?

Tags: parsing, compilation, lexer

In python, the word `in` indicates a operator in an expression `1 in [1,2,3]`. But, in statement `for i in range(10)`, it indicates a keyword of 'for' statement. I wrote a lexer based on regular expression. I use the rule `(\+|-|\*|/|is|in)` to match operator and `(for|in|if|elif|else)` for keywords. I don't know if I should put `in` in the rule of operator or keywords. Both of them will lose one meaning. It seems that I should solve this in parsing. But I need give `in` a label in tokenizing. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Call it "token_in" :) It's usually better not to categorize in your lexer; the parser is responsible for analyzing the syntactic purpose of a token.

In any case, I don't see the point of the lexer producing a single token type for different keywords. `if` and `else` are syntactically distinct tokens, and the parser wants to know that it is seeing an `if`; the fact that it is presented with a "keyword" is not particularly useful to it.